# display: inline or dsplay: inline block not making my list horizontal

Tags: html, css, list, inline

I'm trying to make a list of 3 items appear horizontal instead of vertical.
However using display: inline or display: inline block. Hasn't worked.
I tried float: left but this made the page very messy didn't work and also expanded the footer and header for some reason. This is the page: http://www.ottawaydental.com/patients/

Here is my CSS:

```
/*Patients Style*/


/*Trying to line up the 3 .pdfs*/   

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.doc-thumb {
    display:inline block;
    text-align:center;
}
div {
    display:inline block;
    width: 960px;
}
.docs {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline block;
}
```

Here is my HTML for the list:

```
<!--Container!-->
<div class="docs">
    <ul>
        <li class="docs">
            <figure class="doc-thumb">
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Transfer%20Consent Form General.pdf">
                    <img alt="General Consent Form" src="http://www.ottawaydental.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/consentgeneral.png">
                </a>
            </figure>
            <h4>
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Transfer%20Consent Form General.pdf">General Consent Form</a>
            </h4>
            <p>A general consent form for transferring patient records from another dental practice.</p>
        </li>
        <li class="docs">
            <figure class="doc-thumb">
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Transfer%20Consent Form Pickup&Associates.pdf">
                    <img alt="Pickup & Associates Consent Form" src="http://www.ottawaydental.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/consentpickup.png">
                </a>
            </figure>
            <h4>
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Transfer%20Consent Form Pickup&Associates.pdf">Pickup & Associates Consent Form</a>
            </h4>
            <p>A consent form for transferring patient records from Pickup & Associates.</p>
        </li>

        <li class="docs">
            <figure class="doc-thumb">
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Medical%20History Form.pdf">
                    <img alt="Medical History Form" src="http://www.ottawaydental.com/wp-content/uploads  /2014/07/medicalhistorylogo.png">
                </a>
            </figure>
            <h4>
                <a href="http://ottawaydental.com/Documents/Medical%20History Form.pdf">Medical History Form</a>
            </h4>
            <p>A form to fill out your medical history prior to your appointment.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--Container end!-->
```

Any tips on how to fix the list would be appreciated. Like I said I have switched between inline and inline block as well as tried float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, the right one to use is `inline-block`, even so don't forget to change the `div` width as big as your 3 li's so it can be arranged side by side.

```
ul{list-style-type: none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.doc-thumb {display:inline-block;text-align:center;}
div {display:inline-block;width: 1500px;}
.docs {text-align:center;display:inline-block;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4pen/)..

Answer (score 0):

The correct css property is `display:inline-block;`

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error. It is `display:inline-block` not `display:inline block`

```
.doc-thumb {display:inline-block;text-align:center;}
div {display:inline-block;width: 960px;}
.docs {text-align:center;display:inline-block;}
```